# Smullyan on trees

Tags: first-order-logic

I'm looking at the very first page of Raymond Smullyan's *First-Order Logic* and he talks about *trees*, defining an unordered tree $\mathcal{T}$ as a collection of the following

- A set $\mathcal{S}$ of elements called *points*.
- A function, $\mathcal{l}$, which assigns to each point $x$ a positive integer $\mathcal{l}(x)$ called the *level* of $x$.
- A *relation* $x\mathcal{R}y$ defined in $\mathcal{S}$ which we read as "$x$ is a *predecesor* of $y$" or "$y$ is a *successor* of $x$." This relation must obey the following conditions.
- $C_1$: This is a unique point $a_1$ of level $1$. This point we call
  the *origin*  of the tree.
- $C_2$: Every point other than the origin has a unique predecessor.
- $C_3$:  For any points $x$, $y$, if $y$ is the successor of $x$, then $\mathcal{l}(y) = \mathcal{l}(x) + 1$.

This seems to have a Peano's numbers feel to it. He goes on to further define *trees*. So I'm wondering where this came from? Does anyone know of another text that or resource that describes this *tree*? Is this parallel to anything else?

Comment: It seems to come from describing how a tree looked like in his head.

Comment: See [Tree (graph theory)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(graph_theory))

Comment: @AmatsukiLove: No doubt. But that was quite a head.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA: I'm just an amateur, i.e., no deep graph experience. So I did a quick read of the Wiki article, but I'm not finding the set theory or the "Peano-like" tie-in RS is making above in the graph version of trees. He seems to be doing a more general take on trees, no? I do see "level" and "successor" in comp-sci tree treatments, etc, but no set theory or Peano. BTW, I've always had trouble with Peano explanations of how the successor must be just one integer "next". RS solves that (at least in my mind) with his $C_3$ rule. All in all this amazes me -- and it's just the first page!

Comment: It is a "tree" written upside-now: a single point as *root* or *origin*: the point $a_1$ of level 1. And for each point of level $n$ a number (not necessary finite) of *immediate successors* of level $n+1$. The condition of uniqueness of predecessor avoids "loops". And yes, the "Peano-like" definition is exactly so: it is a definition by recurrence, that generalize usual Induction on natural numbers; see also [Structural Induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_induction).